# Fading out the last character in a block of text on overflow using CSS

Tags: html, css, angular

What I need to implement is a text overflow effect, but instead of a "..." truncate which you would get by using `text-overflow: ellipsis` it should be a fade out on the last character. The element that should have this is a block of text, something like:

[image]

Multiple lines are allowed, if the text has no whitespaces and can't fit in one row, then `break-word` will be applied. A maximum of 5 lines are allowed so the fade should occur on the last character when the text can't fit considering the given `max-height`. Currently I have the following:

```
span {
  overflow: hidden;
  text-align: center;
  word-break: break-word;
  max-width: 72px;
  max-height: 75px; // line height * 5
}
```

I tried using

```
-webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(130deg, #000 80%, transparent);
```

to achieve an effect which is similar, but this one fades out too many characters.

Is there a way to do this using only CSS?

Comment: when do you want the effect to occure ? If there can be multiple lines, then no ellipse should occure... Do you always want the last letter to have a fade effect ?

Comment: A maximum of 5 lines are allowed, so if the text would not fit in that given height that's when the "truncation" should occur on the final character, so at the bottom right corner of the `span` element. In the code example that's what the max-height rule is for, I forgot to clarify that. I'll edit.

Comment: Any script trying to detect what is the pixel length of a string is not fully accurate. So you can't really know the x position of the last visible character. What you can do in JS is limiting to a number of characters, and if so, remove the remaining characters, and put the last character in a span, with a fade effect. But the prefered solution is simply not trying to fade :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the issue was not solved in a CSS only way. As I don't want want to always have the fade-out effect at the last character in the text block, but only when the maximum line height is reached (75px is the max, each line is 15px high). I'm checking on the height of the `span` element using `@ViewChild` and I set the fade-out CSS class using `Renderer2`.

SCSS:

```
  span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    word-break: break-word;
    max-width: 72px;
    max-height: 75px; // line height * 5
    position: relative;
 }
  
  .fade-out-text {
   ::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 12px;
    height: 12px;
    background: linear-gradient(to left, white, transparent);
 }
}
```

Angular:

HTML

```
<span #ref>{{ text }}</span>
```

TS:

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('ref') ref: ElementRef;

  constructor(private readonly renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    // 60 is max line height - line height
    if (this.ref.nativeElement.offsetHeight > 60) {
      this.renderer.addClass(this.ref.nativeElement, 'fade-out-text');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this a [bit old SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70382245/show-more-show-less-text-but-hide-option-if-text-does-not-overflow-angular/70386107#70386107) you has a directive to show more/less

I imagine you can to have a .css

```
.note-field:not(.show)::after{
  content:'';
  width:1rem;
  height: 1rem;;
  padding-left:.5rem;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,0), rgba(255,255,255,1));
  position: absolute;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
}
```